# extract only project name from url using regex

Tags: regex

I would like to only extract value 'prj-*' from the following path using regex,
for example i would like to extract the values 'prj-net-npe-np-data-02' , 'prj-dev-npe-np-data-02', 'prj-stg-npe-np-data-03' from the paths

```
/nonprod/project_overlay/prj-net-npe-np-data-02/.terragrunt-cache
/nonprod/project_overlay/prj-dev-npe-np-data-02/.terragrunt-cache
/nonprod/project_overlay/prj-stg-npe-np-data-03/.terragrunt-cache
```

Comment: Try `prj-[^\/]+`

Comment: Why try regex? Just use `.slice(25, -18)`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks much it worked, can you explain what it does pls

Comment: `prj-[^\/]+` will try to find string that begins with `prj-` and then one or more characters that are **not** `/`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
(?<=\/nonprod\/project-overlay\/)(.*)(?=\/\.terragrunt-cache)
```